# Cannot read property 'newPost' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to query the username from a different collection to then be able to insert into another collection

this is the **Post.js** file

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');

    var user = require('./Users.js'); 

var PostSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    uid : String,
    text: String,
    usename: String,
    date: Date,
    upvotes: Number,
    downvotes: Number
}); 


var Post = module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);


module.exports.newPost = function(data){
    var userid = data.uid;
    var username = '';
    user.User.findOne({_id:userid}, function(err,data){
        if(err) req.flash('error_msg','Invalid username');
        console.log(data)
    });

};
```

this is the **route Index.js** file

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var Posts = require('../models/Post.js');
var uid = '';

router.get('/', ensureAuthenticated, function (req, res) {
    uid = req.query.uid;
    console.log(uid);
    res.render('index')
})


router.post('/', function(req, res){
    var post = req.body.post;
    var date = Date();
    var postData = {
        uid : uid,
        text: post,
        usename: uid,
        date: date,
        upvotes: 0,
        downvotes: 0
    };
    console.log(postData);
    Posts.newPost(postData);
});

function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next){
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        return next();
    } else {
        req.flash('error_msg','You are not logged in');
        res.redirect('/users/login');
    }
}


module.exports = router;
```

This is the **User.js** file

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

// User Schema
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        index:true
    },
    password: {
        type: String
    },
    email: {
        type: String
    },
    name: {
        type: String
    }
});

var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

When I run the server and submit to get the username I get the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'newPost' of undefined
   at /home/a0_/Projects/Node/forum/routes/index.js:26:12
```

The entire code is available at https://github.com/nerditall/forum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Mongoose instance methods should be attached to the schema:

```
PostSchema.methods.newPost = function(...) {...}
```

Scroll to "Instance methods" http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html